# Customizer JS API

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

Okay so I have been trying to educate myself to create new panels sections and controls dynamically using customizer's JS API.

It has been frustrating few days and I was unable to get the exact way to achieve this via JS API.

So far, this is some thing I am doing to make it happen but with no success:

```
    // for Settings
    api.create( 
        params.id, 
        params.id, 
        params.default, 
        params.args 
    );

    // for controls
    var controlConstructor = api.controlConstructor[params.type];
    var control = new controlConstructor(params.id, {
        params: params,
        previewer: api.previewer
    });
    api.control.add( 
        params.id, 
        control 
    );

     //for Sections
     var section = new api.Section(params.id, { 
        params: params
     }); 
    api.section.add( params.id, section );
    api.section('section_id').activate();
```

None of them seem to work as the section doesn't appear and I have to run `api.section('section_id').activate()` twice in console to make the section appear, the same is with control.

Answer (score 2):

1) Maybe bind to the api.ready state which may fix having to call your section twice

```
(function($, api){
  api.bind( 'ready', function() {...

  }
})(jQuery);
```

I saw a note in trac that said "Note that the APIs for dynamically-added controls, and APIs for JS-templated custom Sections and Panels are not yet available as of WordPress 4.2. See #30741." Reading that trac ends with "likely not for 4.5 right now" so your efforts may be futile =(

2) For reference, the wp_customize JS API can be found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js). This [link](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/27/toward-a-complete-javascript-api-for-the-customizer/) may be useful as well.

3) I don't have enough rep for a third link but you might look at Kirki.org which is a helper framework for customizer fields. Kirki is pretty active on Github too.

4) On the PHP side, you can use the "active_callback" option on your field array to dynamically present fields.

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'some_single_page_specific_option', array(
  'label'           => esc_html__( 'Single Page Option' ),
  'section'         => 'my_page_options',
  'active_callback' => 'if_is_singular',
));

function if_is_singular(){
  if( is_singular() ){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: `Note that the APIs for dynamically-added controls, and APIs for JS-templated custom Sections and Panels are not yet available as of WordPress 4.2.` That sums it up. :(

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest instead of reinventing the wheel, maybe you will consider this framework as a base for your projects. http://wpshed.com/wordpress-theme-customizer-framework/.

This one is the best I found while I was learning and looking for frameworks. You can extend this framework with your own custom controls and the below link will help you understand and implement the communication between customizer and customizer-preview via jQuery or javascript.

https://conductorplugin.com/developing-wordpress-customizer-part1/

Comment: Hello Mohit, thanks for the answer but what you have provided doesn't answer the actual question. Even when you use these frameworks, you still have to use JS API. These fraworks doesn't extend customizer's JS API and hence are of no use in this case.

Comment: Hi, you can easily manage that with the other link I provided for the JS files. I am doing it this way and solve my purpose.

Comment: Hmm, support for control, section and panel in JS API came with v4.0 which was launched in Dec 14 and the article you are referring to was written in Sep 14. Are you you are getting what I meant in the question?